# Alkaline ramen noodles shelf life in uncooked state

Tags: noodles, ramen

I do make alkaline noodles by myself in our restaurant. David Chang suggests to mellow-stop the alcalic reaction to add citric acid. I dont have a good experience with it. The character of the dough changes. Its bloating (obviously) a little bit and its more prone to rip and end chewiness is not right. So we are making them every day fresh. As hours pass, they darken into gray-greenish color from previous yellowish. Those who make ramen noodles from scratch and cook them to order, how do you do it? How long do you keep your fresh-cut noodles for cooking to order?

Answer (score 1):

I don't do this in a restaurant situation, but I make plenty of noodles at home.  They last quite a while frozen, and, like pasta, can simply be cooked from their frozen state.  Can you portion and freeze, then cook from frozen?

Comment: @skriatok...meaning you don't have the capacity to freeze?  What is the alkaline you are using?  ...and the flour?

Comment: high gluten spelt and alkali is baked bicarbonate soda=sodium carbonate

Comment: Do they darken if you let them dry (again, like you might with pasta), or do you attempt to keep moist?  ...or maybe try a different flour?   If I understand, the citric keeps them from browning, but you don't like the consistency when using citric.   Another thought... can you blanch, then shock, then reheat when serving?

Comment: I attempt keep moist. Reheating they have 10 minutes perfect texture after being cooked than they are just mediocore. I havent try dry them.